# Creating a Virtual FS from a Shared Memory in Heterogeneous Linux System

Tags: c, embedded-linux, mmap

I'm developing a measurement device, with 2 CPUs and a shared memory:

```
=>[ CPU:0 RTOS/Measurements ]         [ CPU: 1 Linux/User]
                 \                   /          |   
                  \[ Shared Memory ]/           |
                     struct HotData              /measure
                       { int x;          ->              /x
                         char[20] y;     ->              /y
                         long z; };      ->              /z
```

Currently, I have a shared memory, where CPU-0 measures some data and cyclically updates the structure "HotData". I do not want to touch the code on CPU-0 for real-time limitations. On the other hand, the Linux kernel can access this shared space and read the latest data.

Next, I want to create a "super lightweight" virtual filesystem on Linux to map those data fields, each to a file. So any user app/script can easily access "/measure/x" for example and get the latest measurement.

1. What's the fastest (lightweight) way to map the data from the shared physical address into a user-space file?
2. For sure I have to implement the open/read functions for the VFS, is there a quick example/project to follow?

Comment: The fastest way is actually to not do a file-system, but do a `mmap("/dev/mem
, physical address of shared region)` ; assuming this is in I/O mapped memory.

Comment: Thanks @HaltState, but how can I expose different files out of /dev/mem. Like in my example /dev/mem[0:3] -- maps to --> /dev/mem/x

Comment: You would not have isolation - eg, you can't protect x versus y versus z.
Instead, when you map /dev/mem you are mapping a 4KB page of physical space into the user's space.  The user code then accesses x,y, and z by offsets.

Comment: Correct.  Even better,  with read-only pages, no isolating is needed. But access by offset is not intuitive enough for my users. How can I map virtual files to those offsets? Without performance overhead ..

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to look at [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) (Filesystem in User Space).  It's a filesystem driver (shipped by default with many Linux distributions) that allows you to `mount` a virtual filesystem provided by normal unprivileged application/process.
(Think NFS, but local - and it's not restricted to the NFS protocol.  There are existing FUSE solutions for mounting an remote SFTP servers, and even one presenting Wikipedia as a file/directory structure, if I recall...)

There's bindings and libraries for loads of languages - there's an [example in Python](https://www.stavros.io/posts/python-fuse-filesystem/) which shows just how easy it is to implement a virtual filesystem with it.

Sounds like you might be working in C/C++, in which case you probably want [`libfuse`](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/hello.c) (official example code linked).  There's what appears to be a straightforward [C tutorial over on Medium](https://medium.com/@jain.sm/file-system-in-user-space-example-a63a21236270).

Comment: Thanks @wally, but I think fuse comes with a large overhead in terms of performance. I believe it's not suitable for my embedded measurement device.

Comment: If the context switching between kernel and user mode for FUSE is too expensive for your embedded application, I fear you may have to resort to writing some sort of kernel level functionality.  At that point, I’m not sure that the overhead of revealing the data as a file system is going to do you any favours generally though?